# Dont round integer when pulling from MySql

Tags: php, mysql

In my database I have an amount which is 3554.86

When I pull it from mysql it automatically rounds off to 3555

```
$amount = $row['amount'];
```

How can I pull it without rounding it off?

Thanks.

Comment: This question will probably be closed as a duplicate soon. If the answers from the duplicates don't fully address your question please edit it to include why and flag this for re-opening. Thanks!

Comment: How do you store it in MySQL? As integer or as float?